# Did Roman prosperity peak right on the eve of collapse (in particular c. 399)?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire

John Rapley and Peter Heather (*Why Empires Fall*, [2023](https://books.google.com/books?id=0itHEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT25), in Ch. 1 "Party Like It's 399"):

> Rural population densities, and consequently overall agricultural output, reached maximum levels in the late-imperial period. And since Rome’s was overwhelmingly an agricultural economy, there’s not the slightest doubt that Gross Imperial Product – the total economic output of the Roman world – reached higher peaks in the fourth century than at any previous point in the entirety of Roman history.

> This is a staggering discovery. A massive and ever-expanding dataset – the number of pottery shards buried in the earth is beyond number – has demonstrated that the trajectory of Roman macro-economic development was exactly the opposite of what the narrative of decline had supposed. As a result, this unshakeable accumulated tonnage of new evidence has necessarily forced a rethink of the much more limited checklist on which the old orthodoxy had been based. ...

> What used to be taken as clear evidence of economic decline, isn’t. Gibbon was wrong. The Roman Empire did not endure a long, slow decay from its second-century Golden Age, until its fall became inevitable in the fifth. Imperial prosperity peaked right on the eve of collapse. The spokesman of AD 399, while certainly serving the interests both of himself and the regime that employed him, was neither stupid nor criminally duplicitous in proclaiming a new Golden Age.

Is the above correct?

(My understanding was that Rome had probably begun declining in the 3rd century and was certainly declining in the 4th century, but the above authors seem to be saying that this common layperson's understanding is from an older and now debunked historiography.)

Comment: Does this source rest its claim *just* on the number of pottery shards in the ground? Single-item archaeological data like that can *easily* give wrong impressions.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_economy) points to evidence such as atmospheric lead pollution and dates of Mediterranean shipwrecks which may seem to suggest a decline in the 3rd and 4th centuries.

Comment: The first paragraph makes an argument about total gross imperial product. If you want to talk about a golden age you want to look at imperial product per head. If you have more and more people but there are getting poorer and poorer you can certainly speak of a decline even if the total production is increasing.